# Jquery Ajax stream audio in binary format

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, audio, stream

an audio file in various formats (mp3,ogg etc) stored in different servers with unique urls, the audio files are stored in binary format.
All the files are create from a call to the ispeech.org api, for text to speech transform

And i have a simple html page with a div called play, is it possible to load the the audio file somehow (maybe ajax) on dom ready and when the user click on play start playing the audio file?
I can't use flash nor jquery plugins (such as jplayer) just pure jquery/js or html5
Any suggestions?

One example of a url of streaming audio is [here](http://api.ispeech.org/api/rest?apikey=developerdemokeydeveloperdemokey&action=convert&voice=usenglishfemale&text=This%20is%20the%20text%20I%20want%20to%20convert)

And the api documentation is [here](http://www.ispeech.org/api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is play a file, and html5 is OK, maybe take a look at HTML5 Audio:

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp

Comment: I want to stream dynamically this mp3, audio element is not that suitable

Comment: @Ian It's just the most basic example of how to use the html5 audio element, probably not too much to go wrong.

Comment: @theodore could you clarify what you mean by 'stream' in this case?  is it something that is being recorded live?  do you just need to play it? do you need to stream it to your decoder? are you doing this from a smartphone?

Comment: link is dead. link only answers are not recommended for this reason (I realize this was from 4 years ago, but still shows up on a google search. Maybe consider fixing this).

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute of the `audio` element contains a URL. If you are already using something else to create the streaming MP3 file, and it has a URL, then you should be able to simply set that URL to the `src` attribute.