# jQuery ajax not working with 'blob' dataType

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to append to a media source buffer with jQuery ajax.

The following always results in `error`.

```
 $.ajax({url: 'streaminit.mp4', dataType: 'blob', async: false,
                    error: function() {
                        console.log('error');
                    }}).done(function(frag) {
                    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(frag));
                    console.log(new Uint8Array(frag));
                });
```

The request works if I set the `dataType` to `text` but then it fails when appending the source. I presume because the type is wrong.

Comment: `dataType` can be xml, json, script, or html -- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327776/jquery-ajax-stream-audio-in-binary-format

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array type to `Uint8Array` for this to work. Try returning JSON, like:

```
{ 'data': [] }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the team have plans to implement in jQuery 1.12

info **[here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1525)**

I guess until then I'll just stick with **[XMLHttpRequest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)**

Comment: How is that first link relevant? Its just talking about removing legacy options